# Get a reference to a Tab Screen button inside a component (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to add a feature where when the user press on a Bottom Tab Icon button it scroll to the top of the component. But, the problem is My Tab Screen contains a nested Top Tab Navigation. So, when I tried to use `useScrollToTop` it worked but for the Top Tab Screen when clicked.

My question is how to get a reference to the original Tab Icon, so I can make an action when it's pressed **inside my component** which is nested.

```
Bottom Tab Navigation Screen -> Top Tab Naivgation (nested) with 2 screen -> screens
```

Here is my TabScreen that I want to make the action on:

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeNavigation}
  options={{
    tabBarButton: (props) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        {...props}
        style={[...props.style, styles.buttonStyle]}
        disabled={currentShapeAnim.name === 'home'}
        onPress={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
          }, 550);
          selectTab('home', jumpHome, bounceHome, wp(35));
        }}>
        {!hideHome && (
          <Shape icon="e-home" shapeAnimations={[bounceHome]} />
        )}
        <Shape icon="f-home" shapeAnimations={[bounceHome, jumpHome]} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

and here is the navigation screens

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const HomeTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
          showIcon: false,
          style: { height: 0 }
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Main" component={HomeList} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Contacts" component={ContactList} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

 ...
return (
<>
  <Stack.Screen name="HomeList" component={HomeTabNavigator}
  <Stack.Screen name="LeftMenu" component={LeftMenu} />
  <Stack.Screen name="LikersList" component={LikersList} />
  ...
</>
```

);

and in HomeComponent:

```
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
  // Prevent default behavior
  console.log('Event:', e);
  // e.preventDefault();

  // Do something manually
  console.log('Tab pressed');
  if (scrollViewRef.current) {
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true })
  }
});

return unsubscribe;
```

}, [navigation]);

This is working for the Top Tab Navigation, but I guess I need a reference to the bottom tab icon.

Comment: Can you add some code

Comment: @ArjunRamdas ok added code now